# Specify program to use when viewing source in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-dev

I use Chrome for 99% of my work, but one application only works in IE. One major problem I have is that the 'View Source' option on XML documents opens the source Notepad, which always seems to screw up the encoding. I've found tutorials about [changing the program used for viewing source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh133451.aspx) for IE9, but in IE11 they've completely redesigned the F12 window and now there's not even a file menu at all.

How can I change the default application that 'View Source' uses in IE11?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ah sorry, I should clarify. For HTML documents, it uses the built-in viewer, but for XML files it uses Notepad.

Comment: Ahhhh, gotcha!  That makes more sense. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s a simple way to make Notepad++ work as the default HTML viewer for Internet Explorer, but not lose coloured HTML views. First create a batch file (say called np.bat) containing the following,

> START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -lxml %1

save the batch file to this directory:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++

Next edit the registry key here to tell IE to use Notepad++ instead of Windows Notepad:

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View
>   Source Editor\Editor Name

change the (Default) registry entry above to:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\np.bat"

[Source](http://dyball.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/using-notepad-as-default-viewer-for-internet-explorer-view-source/)

Comment: Do you know if Notepad++ will leave this file intact across updates?

Comment: The batch file? It should keep it, but to be safe you could always put the batch file in a different folder. :)

Comment: Actually, in my registry there's no entiry for `...\View Source Editor`. (probably because this machine never had IE10 or lower installed?) I'm kind of wary about creating the this as I don't know what the default value should be or any of the other values under this path.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I found [this forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_other/internet-options-html-editor/443a91db-b2df-4bc2-83c0-69fb2a2e14a6) which corroborated the advice and suggested just creating the keys. I did that and it worked--didn't even have to restart IE. I noticed an annoying flash of the console when the batch file executed, so I simply changed the value to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe` and it seems to work just as well without the flash of the console. Thanks for your help.